# Tracking email traffic to Facebook in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, email, facebook, facebook-application

My company is sending an email to our lead file with a link to a Facebook contest app. I know that ExactTarget (our marketing automation software) has the ability to track links, but we want to see in Google Analytics how many people actually made it there. The app we're using (OfferPop) doesn't seem to have the ability to tie in our analytics account (whereas if we created the app ourselves, we could track).

I see two possible solutions, 1) abandon tracking for `Email -> Facebook App` since Analytics won't work, or 2) use an interim page on our website to log the tracking info and then redirect the user to the appropriate page `Email -> Tracking Page -> Facebook App` (probably use JavaScript redirecting here with a setTimeout function to make sure the tracking occurs).

My concern with option 2 is about the email triggering spam filters when seeing the links in the email redirect to another page.

Any experience and/or recommendations on tracking email-> Facebook?

**Edit:** For the sake of accuracy of this question, I learned OfferPop does [include campaign tracking](http://kb.offerpop.com/entries/24858181-Campaign-ad-tracking) for their apps, but it doesn't integrate into Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Most spam filters don't fetch links and check to see if they redirect.  In fact, most newsletter click tracking solutions use a link that tracks and the redirects.

Because it is very common practice, your plan of tracking and then redirecting should be just fine.